# Responsive Three-Column Restack

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering if this is even possible with a MINIMAL amount of javascript or jQuery.

I have a three column layout: colA, colB, colC, with a header and nav above and a footer below.

HTML:

```
<header></header>
<nav></nav>
<div class="container">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-ms-3" id="colA"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6" id="colB"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="colC"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Everything is all fine and dandy across the board, being a bootstrap child. But I was wondering was methods are out there so that when viewing this on a mobile phone, where everything is contracted to a single column, so that the center column (colB) appears on top, rather than between colA and colC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the css flexbox in combination with Mediaqueries

Here is a link to a good tutorial
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: That did it... thank you. just setting the flex-direction to column and the order of each child for media max-width of 400px worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap framework itself already has everything you need to accomplish this without needing to resort to flexbox, additional media queries, or duplicating content.

First, Bootstrap is designed as mobile-first so create your layout just how you would like it to appear at that breakpoint.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-xs-12" id="colB"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12" id="colA"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12" id="colC"></div>
</div>
```

Then you can add the sizing you want for other breakpoints and use bootstrap's `col-*-push-*` and `col-*-pull-*` classes to reorder them to the correct locations.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3" id="colB"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-6" id="colA"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3" id="colC"></div>
</div>
```

More info can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Additionally, you have a `.container-fluid` inside a `.container`. This has no real effect other than giving you an additional 15px of left and right padding. I removed it from my examples.

Here is a live example: http://www.bootply.com/CsUTEnC51Q

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible with a minimal amount of HTML actually. Bootstrap has some built in classes to show or hide elements depending on the current screen resolution. For example,

```
<div class="visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
  // Content
</div>
```

Will render a `<div>` element that is only shown when the screen resolution is extra small, or mobile. These elements come in a `hidden-*` and `visible-*` variation, where `*` is any of the 4 sizes listed above. It is quite possible to design a layout using these variables. In your case:

```
<div class="container-fluid hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3" id="colA">A</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" id="colB">B</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3" id="colC">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="colB">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="colA">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="colC">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which will render 2 `<div>` elements that only show up and rearrange at different screen resolutions. See this example to see what I mean:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/7vmPuhOYC5)

Hope that gives you some insight!